# How to handle pointers to array elements that get invalidated as the array is resized?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Suppose there's code like this:

```
// Create a vector of size 0
std::vector<int> vec;

vec.push_back(1);
int* a = &vec[0];

vec.push_back(2);
int* b = &vec[1];

std::cout << "Element 0: " << &vec[0] << std::endl;
std::cout << "Element 1: " << &vec[1] << std::endl;
std::cout << "a: " << a << std::endl;
std::cout << "b: " << b << std::endl;
```

This piece of code would print out:

```
Element 0: 0082AC58  // != 'a'
Element 1: 0082AC5C  // == 'b'
a: 0082AC18          // != 'Element 0'
b: 0082AC5C          // == 'Element 1'
```

As the second `push_back()` is called, the vector is resized and the pointer `a` is not valid anymore. So, the question is: how should this situation be handled to avoid the invalidation of pointers? Is it possible to somehow "revalidate" the pointers or use some kind of "intermediate indexing"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't make sense . Relying on pointer into vector is surely not a good design as these pointers could be invalidated when vector is resized.

Using pointers into vector could only be understandable when there is explicit need to do so like you want to pass your vector to C API. In that case also you have to make sure that you have taken default size of vector large enough to rule out any chance of rellocation.

Below is valid example of passing vectors to C API.

```
// C API: this function takes a pointer to an array of at most arraySize
// doubles and writes data to it. It returns the number of doubles written,
// which is never more than maxNumDoubles.

size_t fillArray(double *pArray, size_t arraySize);

vector<double> vd(maxNumDoubles); // create a vector whose
                                  // size is maxNumDoubles
vd.resize(fillArray(&vd[0], vd.size())); // have fillArray write data
                                         // into vd, then resize vd
                                         //to the number of
                                         // elements fillArray
```

Comment: Since C++11, you have `vd.data()` instead of `&v[0]`.